# Search Entire collection without knowing the structure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How do I do regex search on schema that is unstructured.

This is my schema:

```
var phoneSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    img: String,
    specs: []   
});
```

This is example of the data

```
{
    "name": "Apple iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular",
    "img": "http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/apple-ipad-mini-final.jpg",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "543f40c5427c1034a905d5af"
    },
    "specs": [
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"2G Network\",\"description\":\"GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900  - A1454; A1455\"},{\"criteria\":\" \",\"description\":\"CDMA 800 / 1900 / 2100  - A1455\"},{\"criteria\":\"3G Network\",\"description\":\"HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100  - A1454; A1455\"},{\"criteria\":\"4G Network\",\"description\":\"LTE 700 MHz Class 17 / 1700 / 2100  - A1454\"},{\"criteria\":\" \",\"description\":\"LTE 700 / 850 / 1800 / 1900 / 2100  - A1455\"},{\"criteria\":\"SIM\",\"description\":\"Nano-SIM\"},{\"criteria\":\"Announced\",\"description\":\"2012, October\"},{\"criteria\":\"Status\",\"description\":\"Available. Released 2012, November\"}]",
            "title": "General"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Dimensions\",\"description\":\"200 x 134.7 x 7.2 mm (7.87 x 5.30 x 0.28 in)\"},{\"criteria\":\"Weight\",\"description\":\"312 g (11.01 oz)\"}]",
            "title": "Body"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Type\",\"description\":\"LED-backlit IPS LCD capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors\"},{\"criteria\":\"Size\",\"description\":\"768 x 1024 pixels, 7.9 inches (~162 ppi pixel density)\"},{\"criteria\":\"Multitouch\",\"description\":\"Yes\"},{\"criteria\":\"Protection\",\"description\":\"Oleophobic coating\"}]",
            "title": "Display"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Alert types\",\"description\":\"N/A\"},{\"criteria\":\"Loudspeaker \",\"description\":\"Yes, with stereo speakers\"},{\"criteria\":\"3.5mm jack \",\"description\":\"Yes\"}]",
            "title": "Sound"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Card slot\",\"description\":\"No\"},{\"criteria\":\"Internal\",\"description\":\"16/32/64 GB, 512 MB RAM\"}]",
            "title": "Memory"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"GPRS\",\"description\":\"Yes\"},{\"criteria\":\"EDGE\",\"description\":\"Yes\"},{\"criteria\":\"Speed\",\"description\":\"DC-HSDPA, 42 Mbps; HSDPA, 21 Mbps; HSUPA, 5.76 Mbps, LTE, 100 Mbps; EV-DO Rev. A, up to 3.1 Mbps\"},{\"criteria\":\"WLAN\",\"description\":\"Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n, dual-band\"},{\"criteria\":\"Bluetooth\",\"description\":\"v4.0, A2DP, EDR\"},{\"criteria\":\"USB\",\"description\":\"v2.0\"}]",
            "title": "Data"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Primary\",\"description\":\"5 MP, 2592 х 1944 pixels, autofocus\"},{\"criteria\":\"Features\",\"description\":\"Geo-tagging, touch focus, face detection\"},{\"criteria\":\"Video\",\"description\":\"1080p@30fps\"},{\"criteria\":\"Secondary\",\"description\":\"1.2 MP, 720p@30fps, face detection, FaceTime over Wi-Fi or Cellular\"}]",
            "title": "Camera"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"OS\",\"description\":\"iOS 6, upgradable to iOS 7.1.2, upgradable to iOS 8.0.2\"},{\"criteria\":\"Chipset\",\"description\":\"Apple A5\"},{\"criteria\":\"CPU\",\"description\":\"Dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9\"},{\"criteria\":\"GPU\",\"description\":\"PowerVR SGX543MP2\"},{\"criteria\":\"Sensors\",\"description\":\"Accelerometer, gyro, compass\"},{\"criteria\":\"Messaging\",\"description\":\"iMessage, Email, Push Email, IM\"},{\"criteria\":\"Browser\",\"description\":\"HTML5 (Safari)\"},{\"criteria\":\"Radio\",\"description\":\"No\"},{\"criteria\":\"GPS\",\"description\":\"Yes, with A-GPS, GLONASS\"},{\"criteria\":\"Java\",\"description\":\"No\"},{\"criteria\":\"Colors\",\"description\":\"Black/Slate, White/Silver\"},{\"criteria\":\" \",\"description\":\"- Siri natural language commands and dictation\\n\\n- iCloud cloud service\\n\\n- Twitter and Facebook integration\\n\\n- Maps\\n\\n- Audio/video player/editor\\n\\n- Photo viewer/editor\\n\\n- Voice memo\\n\\n- TV-out\\n\\n- Document viewer\\n\\n- Predictive text input\"}]",
            "title": "Features"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\" \",\"description\":\"Non-removable Li-Po 4490 mAh battery (16.7 Wh)\"},{\"criteria\":\"Stand-by\",\"description\":\"\"},{\"criteria\":\"Talk time\",\"description\":\"Up to 10 h (multimedia)\"}]",
            "title": "Battery"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Price group\",\"description\":\"http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/price/pg7.gif\"}]",
            "title": "Misc"
        },
        {
            "description": "[{\"criteria\":\"Display\",\"description\":\"\\nContrast ratio: 812:1 (nominal)\"},{\"criteria\":\"Loudspeaker\",\"description\":\"\\nVoice 68dB / Noise 65dB / Ring 75dB\"},{\"criteria\":\"Audio quality\",\"description\":\"\\nNoise -82.8dB / Crosstalk -80.8dB\"}]",
            "title": "Tests"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Let say my query is "Noise 65dB". And it should return this phone.
Could some one help me on the query structure assumedly I have specs as an array but not knowing anything what internal content.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like something went wrong in your import of this data. The entire description appears to be a string. It seems to have meant to be structured data.

Comment: understand that it is structured data, but i'm blindly import it via script and not knowing the internal structure. this is why I am only specify specs as array, instead of manually declare each field. But think about it, if the user query something random, we should be able to index to each field of the array and perform search on it.

Comment: Yes. It's called a text search. But your real problem here is that you should fix this data. It's clearly structured JSON which was just imported as a string.

Comment: indeed, i should not be stringify the json before post. you are correct, i can actually indexing this. because it was a string i was not able to do so. Thanks alot